# Problems with the Geofire library in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, geofire

When I try to implement the geofire library it throws an error, I would like to know if someone can tell me what this error is about, and how can I solve it

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: prueba_geofire@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: firebase@8.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase
npm ERR!   firebase@"^8.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer firebase@"^7.2.0" from geofirex@0.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/geofirex
npm ERR!   geofirex@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/flbarriosgutierrez/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/flbarriosgutierrez/.npm/_logs/2020-11-07T11_09_50_263Z-debug.log
```

Comment: most probably is a bug. Have you tried looking at their issues section (on Github)?

Comment: You could try `npm install`ing it with `--force` and/or `--legacy-peer-deps` if it helps

Comment: So far I can't find an error session